# Rails 4: acts_as_list with complex scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, acts-as-list

My model has a string field, `bar`, that is either `a`, `b`, or `c`. It uses has_ancestry and acts_as_list. I want the list to be scoped on (1) the ancestry, and (2) `bar`, but I want `a` and `b` to be in the same list, but `c` in another list. That is, if `bar` is `a` or `b` then the Foo is active, and should in one list scope, and if `bar` is `c`, then it is inactive and should be listed separately.

Here is what I think the model might look like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where.not(bar: "c") }

  has_ancestry
  acts_as_list scope: [:ancestry, ???]
end
```

The question is, how do I get acts_as_list to scope two values of bar together?

(E.g. something like `scope: 'ancestry = \'#{ancestry}\' AND bar = \'bar\''` would give me three different lists based on bar, not two.)

Let me know if I haven't explained this right. I looked pretty far into google and couldn't find the answer. Thanks!

---

Rails 4 and Ruby 2; latest versions of ancestry and acts_as_list, but that's flexible.

I should add that I have considered adding another database column that is equivalent to `bar == "c"` but I'm hoping for another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the additional database column with a `before_save` callback to set it based on the value in `baz`. I'm also considering switching to ranked-model (https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) instead of acts-as-list but that's another issue.